# How do I get back a deleted src folder on android

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm currently using lynda.com to learn however I ran into issues when I had my Main.java and Second.java conflicting in the Activity folder and Explicit intents folder.then I  accidentally deleted the src folder, how do I get it back? !

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: In Eclipse, right click on the project name / Restore from local history

Comment: Did you tick while deleting ?

Comment: Yes I am using eclipse...yes I right-clicke on the folder and deleted. It is not in my recycle bin either